# Unable to connect backend server with android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i am developing and android application which communicates with the backed server. I Tested my application inside my Working environment its working fine... I am able to connect to the server and i got the response...

But when i went for testing in my clients environment, i was unable to connect to the back end server.. I used their LAN to access web server...

The problem i am having is Unknown Host name..

Insted of giving the host name i gave the ip address to the host and my application got the response successfully from the server, but if i change the ip address to the DNS i was unable to connect..

I Tried several options

1. Tried to set the host ip address in Eclipse -> Window -> Preference -> Android -> Launch. but it didnt work.
2. I Tried to launch the emulator from the command line using the following command
   emulator -avd MYAVD -dns-server X.X.X.X
   this one also didn't work.

Since my time is limited to deploy i need help.